# How to block dragging multiple items at once

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, block, draggable, drag

I've got an Activity with several ImageViews, each with its own OnDragListener and OnTouchListener. When I'm clicking over the display with two fingers at once, and I click on 2 images at the same time, the app sometimes crashes.

How could I block start of another drags and touches at display when one item is actually dragged? I've tried to put setClicable(false) to the whole layout, but it didn't work.

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
        RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_layout);

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View dropView, DragEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    mainLayout.setClickable(false);
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    // some code
                    return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    // some code
                    return false;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                    mainLayout.setClickable(true);
                    // some code
                    return true;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
}
```

**EDIT:** An idea came to my mind - when an item is clicked, remove OnTouchListeners from every other images. But it would be additional load for CPU on every touch. Isn't there a better way?  -->> also NOT WORKING

**EDIT2:** ACTION_DOWN -> `inAction = true;` and it's still not working. When I drag an image over another one and make second, third... touch, it a) drops a picture or worse b) NullPointerException

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "" + inAction);
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(!inAction) {
                    inAction = true;
                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                    return true;
            }
            else if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                inAction = false;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT3:** I'm using style with false `android:windowEnableSplitTouch` for the whole application

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowEnableSplitTouch">false</item>
    <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return; if a flag is true. Namely, set a flag when any of the listeners is triggered. Haven't you thought about it?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. When I hold one image and click elsewhere with another finger, OS still catches that touch and interferes like I would drop the dragged picture on that place.

Comment: Did you silence ACTION_POINTER_DOWN and UP too? http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html

Comment: Check my EDIT2. Turns out that I've got this handled.

Comment: disable multitouch for the ViewGroup using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#splitMotionEvents or http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowEnableSplitTouch

Comment: what does the event.getPointerCount() return?

Comment: When I try hard, it returns 2. I don't get it. How it's possible? I forbid SplitTouch, I've done so much stuff to prevent it and nothing works? :-O

Comment: Maybe the style isn't applied? Did you try to set the property directly?